# After update of ios app is there some automatic restore

Tags: ios

I make an app for iOS and it is on store, and some people use it on their device.
My app make some data to `Documents/`, `Library/Caches/` and `Library/Preferences/`.
After some time I make an update of app and people do update of app.

My question is what will happened to data in `Documents/`, `Library/Caches/` and `Library/Preferences/`.

By my understanding, if iCloud is off, old data is lost.
If iCloud is on, then what ?

If there is some other scenario, please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Files in `/Documents` and `/Library` will be copied during update 
All data will be the same as before update.

Be careful with DataBase (CoreData) updates. If you update you schema you need to make a DB migration.
Read [apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10)

Answer (score 0):

No the app data on the same device will not be lost but, since iCloud is off, data inside the Documents folder will not be synchronized. When the app is updated you are supposed to write all the code that is necessary to reflect eventual changes in data structure but what is already there will stay there.